# Understanding useDispatch and dispatch in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to understand the code that my past colleague has written.

From what I understand, **useDispatch takes in an object that contains the action type and payload**, which will be **compared to all the reducers** and the **state will be changed accordingly**. However, in the below code, he **passes an entire function instead of an object**. My question is why can **useDispatch still function without passing in an object**, as the function does not return anything.

Below is the useDispatch function and the action function.

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e: any): void => {
        dispatch(login("email", "password"));
    };
```

```
export const login =
    (email: string, password: string) =>
    async (dispatch: Dispatch<LoginActions>) => {
        try {
            // Update the store
            dispatch({
                type: USER_ACTIONS.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
            });


            const data = await loginRequest({ email, password });

            dispatch({
                type: USER_ACTIONS.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: data,
            });
        } catch (error: any) {
            dispatch({
                type: USER_ACTIONS.USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
                payload:
                    error.response && error.response.data.message
                        ? error.response.data.message
                        : error.message,
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redux itself, you can only dispatch action which is a plain JS object(or an action creator returns an action, this action is a plain JS object must have a `type` field.). But with various middlewares, you can dispatch various things such as a thunk, plain JS object action, etc. The middleware will transform the action to plain JS object action in the end.

When using the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware, you can dispatch a thunk like this:

```js
const thunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => {
  // logic here that can dispatch actions or read state
}

store.dispatch(thunkFunction)
```

The `login` thunk action creator does return a thunk.

A thunk action creator is a function that may have some arguments, and returns a new thunk function. See [Writing Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#writing-thunks)

Another example, [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware),

> Given a single action with an async payload, the middleware transforms the action to separate pending action and a separate fulfilled/rejected action, representing the states of the async action.

You can dispatch an action with async payload:

```js
const response = dispatch({
    type: 'FIRST',
    payload: new Promise(...),
});
```

Comment: thank you so much that really clears up a lot! I was not aware of such a feature in redux. Just to clarify, so there are multiple use cases (different inputs) for the dispatch function in redux? Not just plain javascript objects but action creators and thunkFunctions etc.